# SSRS Cube parameter with 2 hierarchies on the same dimension

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, cube, olap-cube

I have a data cube (built using SSAS) and I'm querying it using SSRS 2008 R2.
the cube has a simple supplier dimension with two properties/hierarchies:
1. supplier name
2. supplier gk
Every supplier have a distinct gk, and every gk has a distinct name.

So far I've built many reports on this data cube, and many of them  used this dimension as a filer - I had absolutly no problems so far, and everything just went great.
but than my costumers asked me for a simple change - instead of the report parameter showing only the supplier name in the drop down list, they want to see both the name and the gk.

I've tried playing with the MDX of the hidden dataset for that parameter, but with no luck.
Does anybody have an idea on how to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you craete a new virtual dimension that works off the same location hierarchy, but uses both the supplier name and the gk for the member's name? Or edit one of your existing dimensions to add the extra information to it's member names?